# Swift: Remove only the first object from the NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, dictionary, nsuserdefaults

I create the Bus Ticket Booking App. so I have `Dictionary` with the `Array` in it. In which the recent Route search result is save into the `NSUserDefaults`. Now I want to print that result into the one `TableView`.

Now in that `TableView` I only want to show the `last 10` That's all I can do perfectly but the problem is every time the result is save in to the `UserDefaults` so the size of the `UserDefaults` is increase so I just want to remove the `Defaults` So every time my array `element remove` `Repeat While` loop is call the number of the element in the `UserDefaults` (If I i have 30 element into it it run 20 times so like). This is what i'm doing for Dictionary.

```
    var arrSearch = [[String:Any]]()
    var searchBusVC:SearchBusViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            if let arr = UserDefault["Search"] {
                arrSearch.append(contentsOf: (arr as! [[String:Any]]))
                repeat{
                 arrSearch.removeFirst()

                }while (arrSearch.count > 10)

                arrSearch.reverse()
            }
                self.tblSearch.reloadData()
        }
```

So I want to remove the same from the `UserDefaults` Is it possible? This is my Table View Image.

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving `[[String: Any]]` in `UserDefaults` means its like a normal way to remove objects from array. Once you done removing objects from array then save it to `UserDefaults`.

```
 var recentRecords:[[String: Any]]? {
      get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey:"recentRecord")
       }
      set {
        var trimmed: [[String: Any]] = newValue
        // Trim last 10 objects from array
        if newValue.count >= 10 { 
         trimmed = newValue.suffix(10)
        } 

        UserDefaults.standard.set(trimmed, forKey: "recentRecord")
      }
 }
```

Comment: okay. But that remove all the object. I want to keep the last 10 result save. I don't want to remove all.

Comment: trimming condition added. check now

Comment: This doesn't even compile. And don't use `value(forKey` with `UserDefaults` unless you can explain why KVC is needed in this case. Can you?

Comment: for getting a values from UserDefaults use value(forKey:)

Comment: No, the standard API is `object(forKey`, in this case even `array(forKey`